# How to get/generate access token of storefront API

Tags: shopify, laravel-8, shopify-api

I am using https://github.com/osiset/laravel-shopify package to manage Shopify API with laravel 8 and facing the following error:

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
{
"errors": "App must be extendable to create a storefront access token."
}

Trying the following:

```
$shop = Auth::user();
$orders = $shop->api()->rest('POST', '/admin/api/2021-01/storefront_access_tokens.json', ['storefront_access_token' => ['title' => 'mobile']]);
dd($orders);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I want to answer my own question as eventually i was able to found the soluion:
To achive this you must have the following requirements:

1. A public shopify app
2. Enabled sales channel (You can find it in Apps->your app->app setup)
3. Api scopes with following values:

> read_products,write_products,unauthenticated_read_content,unauthenticated_read_customer_tags,unauthenticated_read_product_tags,unauthenticated_read_product_listings,unauthenticated_write_checkouts,unauthenticated_read_checkouts,unauthenticated_write_customers,unauthenticated_read_customers

and the you need to logout(if already logged in) and then re-authenticate with shopify and then You will be able to make it work.

Comment: So, with a custom app that is not public, this won't be possible ?

Comment: @noiseymur maybe its possible but i never tried, You can give it a try and if possible please reply back.

Comment: it worked but only with an offline session token.

Comment: Can confirm that this worked on a Custom App using only step 3 (i.e. specifying a Storefront API scope) and following the directions here: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-node/blob/789f01001d10600e0eb22465f407baadf3213ee2/docs/usage/storefront.md